# What is this syntax for defining binary numbers in ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary

some terminal output is worth a thousand words so lets start with that:

```
[10] pry(main)> 1_000
=> 1000
```

yep, we can define thousands in a readable way in ruby, I know that and everythings fine. Hey, I wonder what would happen if I try and left pad that with zeroes?

```
[9] pry(main)> 001_000
=> 512
```

Well that's weird, it's not binary as that would be 8 hmm...

```
[20] pry(main)> 01_0
=> 8
```

so that's 8... ok, 2**3 is 8, 2**(3*3) is 512 I bet 01_00 is 2**6==64

```
[24] pry(main)> 01_00
=> 64
```

hmm... there's nothing special about the underscore in the number syntax, it's just to make it look nice:

```
[23] pry(main)> 0100
=> 64
```

So what are these numbers called (it's not straight binary... I'm trying to think of what they should be but keep coming up with a blank). In addition why are they so important? could anyone post a link to the documentation describing them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If numbers are prefixed with `0`, it's octal representation.

Similarly, if numbers are prefixed with `0x` or `0X`, it's hexadecimal reprepsentation.

```
0x10
# => 16
0x100
# => 256
```

---

BTW, You can convert numbers to octal, hexadecimal, binary representation using [`%` operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) or [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
'%o' % 512
=> "1000"

'%x' % 256
# => "100"

'%x' % 512
# => "200"

'%b' % 3
# => "11"
```

Comment: It's just octal??? ahhh, of course, I feel stupid for asking now, I know `0x` and `0b` prefix, didn't know `0` I guess it's because I was thinking in thousands due to the underscores I just falsely extrapolated it to binary-thousands. Thanks

Comment: I deleted my answer, as I missed that Mike wasn't actually looking for a binary representation. But I think worth adding `0b` literals an `%b` formatting to this answer, because of likely hits from people looking for that based on question title

Comment: @NeilSlater, Thank you for comment. I added `%b` formatting as you suggested.